# Handling refactorings, template SFINAE tests and lambdas

Tags: c++, templates, lambda, c++17, sfinae

The following (academically built, non working) code has two "problems" that I know how to solve in an ugly way. I would like a pretty one.

```
#include <type_traits>

template<class T> struct Integer {
    Integer(T t) { static_assert(std::is_integral_v<T>, "Must be int"); }
};

template<class T> struct Floating {
    Floating(T t) { static_assert(std::is_floating_point_v<T>, "Must be flating point"); }
};

template<class T> void brol(T t)
{
    Integer i(t); //these two cannot work together
    Floating f(t); 

    template<class U> auto stuff = [] (U& u) -> void //invalid syntax : no template on bloc scope
    { u *= 2; } 

    if(std::is_integral_v<T>)
        stuff(i);
    else
        stuff(f);
}

int main()
{
    brol(2);
    brol(2.0);
}
```

1. Obviously, I cannot build an `Integer` and a `Floating` inside if the function `brol()`, because of the static_asserts. This problem can be easily solved with SFINAE tests, either nicely with `std::enable_if_v` or with some `... -> decltype( ... )` trickery. In the same way, I can also improve the end of the function body and avoid the if/else block
2. The lambda `stuff()` cannot be template (because the compiler states it cannot). I *** could *** make it independent and hide it in a subnamespace, but it's not so great.

HOWEVER, I cannot simply make an SFINAE test with `std::enable_if`, as the prototypes will only differ with their default template arguments and this is illegal (cf. documentation, section Notes in `std::enable_if`).

On the other hand, I don't know how to solve ussie 2 nicely...

Comment: Hm, it's quite unclear what you really want to achieve. Currently the code accomplishes exactly nothing (assuming it compiled), so it's hard to tell what we are allowed to throw out and what you actually want to keep/correct/learn about. Or is this literally for no other purpose than learning about SFINAE etc.?

Comment: Most confusingly, you are trying to do `*= 2` on the structs. Even if all the SFINAE and lambda stuff that you mentioned was "fixed", it still wouldn't make any sense to do that multiplication. If you pass `t` instead of `i`/`f` to the lambda then all the assertion stuff is pointless and it still wouldn't have any effect (because `t` is never used).

Answer (score 1):

It seems to me that `std::conditional` should solve all your problems

```
template <typename T>
void brol (T t)
 {
   using U = std::conditional_t<std::is_integral_v<T>, Integer<T>, Floating<T>>;

   U u{t};

   auto stuff = [] (U & u) -> void { u *= 2; };

   stuff(u);
 }
```

Anyway, the problem with the lambda could be solved also with a generic lambda (as pointed by rustyx)

```
   auto stuff = [] (auto & u) -> void { u *= 2; };
```

Regarding the final if, in C++17 (you're using `std::is_integral_v`, so you're using C++17) you can also use `if constexpr` in similar circustances

```
if constexpr (std::is_integral_v<T>)
    stuff(i);
else
    stuff(f);
```

but remain the problem that you have to define `i` or `f`.

Comment: std::conditional and that 'using' trick really does the thing, thank you !

Answer (score 0):

It's unclear what the purpose of your `Integer` and `Floating` is...

But regarding the "`template<class U> auto stuff = [](U& u)`" part, C++14 does make the lambda a `template` automatically if you simply use `auto` as the parameter type:

```
template<class T> void brol(T t) {

    auto stuff = [](auto& u)
    { u *= 2; };

    stuff(t);
}

int main() {
    brol(2);
    brol(2.0);
}
```